# How long Cookies last, which return with JsonServiceClient Request

Tags: c#, cookies, xamarin.forms, servicestack

I am working with Xamarin-Forms application.To authenticate user I use ServiceStack CredentialAuthProvider.When authentication successfully done I got cookieContainer in response.I want to know how long that cookies last ? 
I am not getting any info about cookie expiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've Authenticated with RememberMe=true then the Users Session is stored against the ss-pid permanent Cookie which is valid until the user logs out (or 20 years). But the Session is only valid as long as it's stored in the Cache (not the lifetime of the Cookie) which defaults to:

```
    public static TimeSpan DefaultSessionExpiry = TimeSpan.FromDays(7 * 2); //2 weeks
    public static TimeSpan DefaultPermanentSessionExpiry = TimeSpan.FromDays(7 * 4); //4 weeks
```

From [SessionFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/SessionFeature.cs).

I.e. 4 weeks for Sessions stored against the ss-pid permanent cookie.

Comment: How can I refresh that expired cookie in both sides ,server and client ?@mythz

Comment: @DhruvGohil you can't refresh an expired cookie as it doesn't exist anymore, you also won't need to refresh an expire a permanent cookie which doesn't expire. You likely want to extend the Users Session, not the Cookie, which you can do by calling IRequest.SaveSession() to resave the Users Session.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail how do I extend session when it is about to expire ?

Comment: How do I extend the session after 4 weeks on server ?Do I have to track the session expiration ? Can you please explain in detail with some code ? @mythz

Comment: @DhruvGohil See the [sliding session example in the docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#sliding-sessions).